# Find a line in a text file

Tags: python

Im trying to make a project where you type in a number and it tells you what is on that line on a separate file but it just won't work.

I've only tried this but my code is:

```
a = input('what file line would you like to read:    ')
file = open('newfile.txt', 'r')
print(file.readlines(a))
file.close()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=io#io.IOBase.readlines

Comment: @erik258 Not quite. The optional argument is a maximum number of *bytes or characters* to read, not a maximum number of lines.

Comment: Good call.  Failed to find that documentation.  So looping `file.readline()` is better for both reasons.

Answer (score 2):

`readlines` returns a **list** containing all the lines from the file. To get a specific line, you can try :

```py
line_number = int(input("what file line would you like to read: "))
with open("newfile.txt", "r") as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    try:
        print(content[line_number - 1])
    except IndexError:
        print("The line number you entered is out of range")
```

Comment: FYI this requires reading the whole file in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `linecache.getline`

```
import linecache
  
line_number = int(input("what line would you like to read: "))
line        = linecache.getline('YourFile.txt', line_number)
  
print(line)
```

When you are done with the file, you can use `linecache.clearcache()` to release the file from memory.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```py
from itertools import islice

a = int(input('what file line would you like to read:    '))

with open('the_file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    print(*islice(f_in, a - 1, a), end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

.readlines() has only one attribute called "hint" which is used as followed:

> Optional. If the number of bytes returned exceed the hint number, no more lines will be returned. Default value is  -1, which means all lines will be returned.

also input returns str as return value and "hint" needs to be an integer.

To open a file use the "with" statement like this, for good practice and read the file with this snippet so you don't have to worry about closing the file after using it.

```
lines_array = []
with open("newfile.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        lines_array.append(line)
```

after this you can do the input part,

```
a = input('what file line would you like to read:    ')
print(lines[int(a)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without importing any additional modules and also (potentially) not reading the entire file:

```
lineno = int(input('Line number (base 1): ')) # should really validate the input here

with open('/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.txt') as foo:
    line = None
    for _ in range(lineno):
        if not (line := foo.readline()):
            # EOF
            print('Not enough lines in the file')
            break
    else:
        print(line)
```